# How to structure Entity in Symfony2

Tags: php, sql, entity-framework, symfony, entity

Help me think how to structure my entity in my Symfony2 project.

I have orders and in the orders you select services for that order. The services has separate prices for different clients. I should even be possible to have individual price for different orders. So the price will be bound to order not to Service or Client.

So far I have made a ManyToMany connection between Entity "Orders" and Entity "Service". That works fine, but I can´t figure out how to do with the separate price for that service. I could make a JSON string in a column in the order, but it feels not a good standard for it.

Comment: First: try to write down all the use cases. It will help you to understand how should it work. Then try to write down the structures of all the tables.
It seems to me that every service should have price. Every client should have some price rate. And in order you need to calculate total price basing on services prices multiplied by user price rate.

Comment: The price have to be more flexible then that. The price can be different from order to order on the same customer.
+1 for writing everything down. I think I have to start there

Comment: Even so, if a price can be different from order to order it *should* depends on something. It might depend on use price rate or time of order or some external condition. While we don't know what exactly the conditions total price depends on we can't suggest anything better.

Comment: It depends on the photographs payroll and client discount. But it will be fixed to the order so the price wont change in older orders when you change the discount. I know I have not given you much information. Thats because I wanted you se this with open eyes and not fixed to my solutions. I think am going for the right direction now. I followed your advice and wrote everything down. It was much easier to have a overlook, and I went up splitting my order into many tables and have whole new approche to it. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: So, there are two more entities: Photograph and Discount. Write down use cases. It will clear everything out.

Comment: Yes it´s a lot of entities after I start to write it down. Before I was thinking it was a waste of time writing this stuff down. But now I see it was very useful and helpful. Thanx again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way for that is to create a `Price` table in relation with ̀`service` and ̀`Customer` It will be your price grid.

But be careful with your Order entity. An order should never be directly in relation with your service entity. Or be sure you're never cascading anything.

Comment: It seems to be logic. I´ll try this tomorrow and see how it looks like